# Python garbage collector for large data formatting program

Tags: python, arrays, excel, garbage-collection, large-files

I have written a program to read through a folder of excel files and load each file into the program. It then takes the data and creates an array of zeros of size (3001,2001), which will be iterated through and the corresponding coordinate values from excel will put changed to ones. The array is then reshaped to a size of (1,6005001). I am using tensorflow to reshape the array since the program considers it a tuple, but the final values are stored in a numpy array. I finally store the final formatted array into a csv file named "filename_Array.csv" and the program moves on to the next excel file to be formatted. I am running Python on Eclipse with tensorflow installed

The issue I am running into is that some values are being cached in memory, but I can not figure out what it is. I have tried explicitly deleting large variables that will be reinitialized and having gc.collect() to clean the inactive memory that is stored. I am still seeing a steady increase in memory usage until around 25 files formatted, then the computer begins freezing up as all of the RAM on my pc (12GB) is being used. I know that python automatically clears memory for values that are completely unreachable by the program, so I am not sure if this is an issue with fragmenting of RAM or something else. 
Sorry for the walls of text, I am just trying to give as much info to the problem as possible.

Here is a link to a screenshot of my [performance tab](https://imgur.com/a/CvNJE) while running the program through about 24 files before I had to terminate the program due to the computer freezing.

Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='2'
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import csv

import gc

path = r'C:\Users\jeremy.desforges\Desktop\Eclipse\NN_MNIST\VAM SLIJ-II 4.500'

def create_array(g,h,trainingdata,filename):
    # Multiplying by factors of 10 to keep precision of data
    g = g*1000
    h = h*1
    max_g = 3000
    max_h = 2000

    # Initializes an array with zeros to represent a blank graph
    image = np.zeros((max_g+1,max_h+1),dtype=np.int)
    shape = ((max_g+1)*(max_h+1))

    # Fills the blank graph with the input data points
    for i in range(len(h)):
        image[g[i].astype('int'),h[i].astype('int')] = 1

    trainingdata.close()
    image = tf.reshape(image,[-1,shape])

    # Converts tensor objects to numpy arrays to feed into network
    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
    image = sess.run(image)

    np.savetxt((filename + "_Array.csv"), np.flip(image,1).astype(int), fmt = '%i' ,delimiter=",")

    print(filename, "appended")
    print("size",image.shape)
    print(image,"=  output array")
    del image,shape,g,h,filename,sess
    return

# Initializing variables

image = []
shape = 1
g = 1.0
h = 1.0
f = 1
specials = '.csv'
folder = os.listdir(path)

for filename in folder:

    trainingdata = open(filename, "r+")
    filename = str(filename.replace(specials, ''))
    data_read = csv.reader(trainingdata)

    for row in data_read:
        in1 = float(row[0])
        in2 = float(row[1])    
        if (f==0):
            z_ = np.array([in1])
            g = np.hstack((g,z_))
            q = np.array([in2])
            h = np.hstack((h,q))
        if (f == 1):
            g = np.array([in1])
            h = np.array([in2])
            f = 0

    create_array(g,h,trainingdata,filename)

    gc.collect()
    image = []
    shape = 1
    g = 1.0
    h = 1.0
    f = 1
```

Comment: At least you must do `with open(filename, "r+") as trainingdata: ...`

Comment: At a guess, `trainingdata = open(filename, "r+")`. You never close the file and build multiple objects based on what's in that file.

Comment: That's my error, I included it before and accidentally deleted it trying to find the issue. The issue unfortunately persists even with closing the input files.